# Is there a way to convert a JS array in JSON or array in Android?

Tags: javascript, java, android, json

I have an Android application that gets data from a website source page, in particular a JavaScript array of object. I want to convert it in something that I can manage in Android. Is there a way to do that?

I tried to use a WebView (that's not going to be seen by the user) to use the evaluateJavascript method, but with no luck.

As result, I would get an array of this objects, so I can manage them in Java.

Edit:

This is an example of a string that i want to convert:

var objects = [

```
                {
        id: "1823746",
        type: "dog",
    },
    {
        id: "2346123",
        type: "cat",
    }
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gson library help you.

```
new Gson().fromJson("[...]", MyArrayListOfMyObject.class)

class MyArrayListOfMyObject extends ArrayList<MyObject> {}

class MyObject {String id; String type;}
```

Comment: I get this error : _com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 1 column 31828 path $[60].Something_ Is it because I don't have double quotes in every field, correct

Comment: MyArrayListOfMyObject array = new Gson().fromJson("[{id: \"1823746\",type: \"dog\"},{id: \"2346123\",type: \"cat\"}]", MyArrayListOfMyObject.class);

Log.d("array :", array.get(0).id);

Comment: there are two Inappropriate comma in you json array

Comment: [ {id: "1823746", type: "dog"},{id: "2346123",type: "cat",}]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, i had to do something more (Es: id -> "id") but the Gson library made the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library will convert a JSON string into an array of objects.

Comment: The problem is that the string contains a JavaScript array.. How can I convert it to JSON?

Comment: Are you able to add an example of the string you're trying to convert?